# How can i set the thumbnail size in blueimp jquery fileupload?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

Its crazy, but i was not able to google that.

My call:

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    done: function(e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function(index, file) {
            // do something with file and index
        });
    }
});
```

There should be an option to set thumbnail size somewhere, right?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking form displaying the height or width of the uploaded img?

To change width/height of uploaded img is very simple:
You will find the most options in:

> ./server/php/UploadHandler.php

there you can change the size of uploaded img **on line 146**

```
        'thumbnail' => array(
            // Uncomment the following to use a defined directory for the thumbnails
            // instead of a subdirectory based on the version identifier.
            // Make sure that this directory doesn't allow execution of files if you
            // don't pose any restrictions on the type of uploaded files, e.g. by
            // copying the .htaccess file from the files directory for Apache:
            //'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/thumb/',
            //'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/thumb/',
            // Uncomment the following to force the max
            // dimensions and e.g. create square thumbnails:
            //'crop' => true,
            'max_width' => 205,
            'max_height' => 155 
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

Redirect the files to your own uploader server side script:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: 'my_uploader.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        ...
});
```

Set the options of the UploadHandler object. All the resized versions (even more then one!) of the incoming image can be configured there.

my_uploader.php:

```
<?php
include "lib/jQuery-File-Upload/server/php/UploadHandler.php";

$options = array(
    'upload_dir'=>'photo/',
    'upload_url'=>'photo/',

    'image_versions' => array(
                '' => array(), // original

                'medium' => array(
                    'max_width' => 800,
                    'max_height' => 800
                ),
                'thumbnail' => array(
                    'crop' => true,
                    'max_width' => 300,
                    'max_height' => 300
                )
            )
    );
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);
?>
```

Comment: Well, its easier to just set them in UploadHandler.php, like the accepted answer suggests.

Comment: I hardly dislike to make changes in the 'library files'. In case of update or re-use of the code you are in trouble. Ok - accepted answer does the work. This seems to me more clean.

Comment: yes, i'd like this approach more, too, but this library is not installed via composer/etc and it even says "edit me" itself. i remember doing the same edit some years ago and going through the same thought process. but in the end this is no file that will be updated for years. ty for your idea though, +1

Comment: Absolutely agree. The library is very non-formal and it states edit-me-here explicitly in the code. Both ways are correct and legal. Just wanted to point out the "config way" for the more formal ones.